# elapsedRealtime analogue for Object.wait

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait, notify

I used `Object.wait(timeout)` in my android app service. But it does not count time spent in "deep sleep mode". I use AlarmManager to wakeup my app periodically, so waking from deep sleep is not the problem. The problem is that `wait(60000)` not terminates after 100 seconds of deep sleep.

As i read on [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) help page, `object.wait` uses [uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29) method, which stops counting in deep sleep. For my needs it will be better to use [elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29).

How can i implement an analogue of `Object.wait(timeout)` but using [elapsedRealtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) method? Or what can i use instead?

---

One of the tasks i use this method for is to generate "ping" packet to send via network when no other packets are in queue for some amount of time.

Comment: so why `wait()` for sleeping? for sleep go for `sleep()`, there is a big difference between sleep and wait dude, [read this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#wait0)
and would you share your code dude?!

Comment: i use `wait` because i want to stop waiting when `notify` is called. Anyway `sleep` has the same issue.

Comment: You're almost there. You're already using AlarmManager - why not do it all with it instead of wait/sleep?

Comment: you may interrupt the thread in order of skipping the rest of the idle time sleeping, the wait/notify is designed to synchronize threads, and try to sleep 10000 for 6 times.

Comment: @Pescis because i have several threads for several simultaniuos purposes. I use many wait calls and notify is used from other threads. I'll try to call notify from AlarmManager if timeout reached, but for this i need to store an array of waiting objects with their timeouts.

Comment: @user2511414 interrupt is ised to terminate thread, not to stop waiting

Comment: @Tishka17 how do you say interrupt is used for terminating?! it's completely wrong, so you may need to read [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#shuttr)

Comment: @user2511414 interrupt is used to terminate thread which is waiting for something. Using just some flag will not do the work as thread can be sleeping for long time. I do not think interrupt can be sent when i'm not going to terminate thread, so i do not see what is the problem.

Comment: @Tishka17 C'mon there is no any specific way to terminating a thread in java, for sleeping a thread for a specif time it's better to use `sleep()`, the `interrupt()` just sends an exception to the thread IF and IF thread is either join, sleep or wait state, it doesn't terminate it.

Comment: @user2511414 I meaned that when calling interrupt i catch `InterruptedException` and return from `run` method. In contrast to `notify` which is used to finish waiting and continue doing operations

Comment: @Tishka17 a thread is terminated when the run method is finished, so there is no surprise, you just need surround the `sleep()` with a individual try-catch, so after the catch continue working.

Comment: A partial wake lock might solve your issue: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: @SherifelKhatib partial wake lock does not allow processor to sleep at all. It'ww be enough for me just wake up periodically

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned(at comments) `interrupt()` causes termination(kill) the thread, while this is completely wrong, it just throws an exception to the waiting/joining/sleeping thread.

```
public void Foo implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
   //do some work
   try{Thread.sleep(10000);}catch(Exception ex){/*when thread got interrupted*/}
   //do something else
  }
}
```

the issue is here, because you put all the business inside a `try` block, so interrupting causes code jump into the `catch` block where there is no any business after this, so this is not a thread thing.

Comment: i understande that interrupt does not cause thread to stop. I stop current thread manually in `catch (InterruptedException e)`. But it is not about the question i asked. Can you privide any information about changing the time measurement method in `wait` call?

Comment: @Tishka17 would you please share the code you have tried buddy?!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using plain Object.wait() or Thread.sleep() I would suggest you to use any of the following:

1. Use a java.util.concurrent.newScheduledThreadPool which gives you ability to schedule a task with fixed interval or delay. Initializing the thread pool with threadCount = 1 gives you a single thread.
2. Use a java.util.Timer which allows you to schedule TimerTask.

I think 1. is a preferred method.

In case you have specific requirement that you want to plug in your timer object or use a specific or 3rd party timing provider, what you need to do is to write your own scheduler which wraps the ScheduledExecutorService, then convert the time using your own timer or get time from your own timer. Basically you launch a scheduled task on the wrapped service with your own time calculation.

I have a sample of such scheduler in my actor model as below. Take a look at the DefaultScheduler in this package. It might be a bit buggy (I haven't tested it fully yet) but it should give you a good idea.

http://sourceforge.net/p/jalgo/code-0/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/as/algo/threading/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it does exactly what you want but I wrote this to pause for a certain period of time but to let other threads wake me up prematurely.

It uses a `BlockingQueue` internally to do it's sleeping so it avoid using `sleep` and `wait` and all the grief that comes with them.

Not sure how it would act under Android, I don't work with it, but I suspect your existing `AlarmManager` work will adapt.

```
/**
 * Use one of these to doze for a certain time.
 *
 * The dozing is fully interruptable.
 *
 * Another thread can stop the caller's doze with either a wakeup call or an abort call.
 *
 * These can be interpreted in any way you like but it is intended that a Wakeup is
 * interpreted as a normal awakening and should probably be treated in exactly the
 * same way as an Alarm. An Abort should probably be interpreted as a suggestion
 * to abandon the process.
 */
public class Doze {
  // Special alarm messages.
  public enum Alarm {
    // Standard timeout.
    Alarm,
    // Forced wake from your doze.
    Wakeup,
    // Abort the whole Doze process.
    Abort;
  }
  // My queue to wait on.
  private final BlockingQueue<Alarm> doze = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
  // How long to wait by default.
  private final long wait;

  public Doze(long wait) {
    this.wait = wait;
  }

  public Doze() {
    this(0);
  }

  public Alarm doze() throws InterruptedException {
    // Wait that long.
    return doze(wait);
  }

  public Alarm doze(long wait) throws InterruptedException {
    // Wait that long.
    Alarm poll = doze.poll(wait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // If we got nothing then it must be a normal wakeup.
    return poll == null ? Alarm.Alarm : poll;
  }

  public void wakeup() {
    // Just post a Wakeup.
    doze.add(Alarm.Wakeup);
  }

  public void abort() {
    // Signal the system to abort.
    doze.add(Alarm.Abort);
  }

  private static long elapsed ( long start ) {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
  }

  // Test code.
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Doze for 1 second at a time.
    final Doze d = new Doze(1 * 1000);
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Start a dozing thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Alarm a = d.doze();
          // Wait forever until we are aborted.
          while (a != Alarm.Abort) {
            System.out.println(elapsed(start) + ": Doze returned " + a);
            a = d.doze();
          }
          System.out.println(elapsed(start) + ": Doze returned " + a);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          // Just exit on interrupt.
        }
      }

    }).start();


    // Wait for a few seconds.
    Thread.sleep(3210);

    // Wake it up.
    d.wakeup();

    // Wait for a few seconds.
    Thread.sleep(4321);

    // Abort it.
    d.abort();


  }

}
```